# Pattern Recognition (Bishop) - Maximum Likelihood

Tags: machine-learning

This refers to Chapter 2, section 2.2 (page 75) - Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Christopher Bishop.

The question is related to calculation of Maximum Likelihood variable:

Maximum likelihood is given as:
$$p(D|\mu) = \prod_{n=1}^{N}\prod_{k=1}^{K}\mu_{k}^{x_{nk}} = \prod_{k=1}^{K}\mu_{k}^{m_{k}} \tag{2.29}$$
where $m_{k} = \sum_{n}x_{nk}$ $\implies$ #occurrences of event $k$, $x_k$, over $n$ trials where, k={1,$\ldots$,K} and, n={1,$\ldots$,N}. Also, $\mu_{k}$ being probability,  and $D$, the observed data.

> Author applies Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$ and take log-likehood
>   of above equation to get: $$\sum_{k=1}^{K}m_{k}ln{\mu_{k}} + \lambda(\sum_{k=1}^{K}\mu_{k} - 1) \tag{2.31}$$  given the 
>   (probability) constraint): $$\sum_{k=1}^{K}\mu_{k} = 1$$
>
> Maximization of eqn. 2.31, w.r.t $\mu_{k}$ and equating it to 0,
>   yields: $$ \mu_{k} = -m_{k}/\lambda \tag{2.32}$$
>   Author substitutes the constraint in eq 2.32 and finally gets:
>   $$
> \mu_k^{ML} = \frac{m_k}{N} \tag{2.33}
> $$

*I am losing it in the last step - my (partial/ wrong) derivation of 2.31 w.r.t. $\mu_{k}$ yields*:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{m_{k}}{\mu_{k}} + \lambda\cdot K = 0$$

I am not able to understand:

1. Where am I going wrong
2. How to move ahead to get the result (only, if my derivation is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial derivative you have calculated is incorrect. You are probably confused by the index k in the equation.
Consider expanding the Langrangian:
$$ L = m_{1}ln\mu _{1}+ m_{2}ln\mu_{2} + ... + m_{K}ln\mu_{K} + \lambda(\mu_{1} + \mu_{2} + ... + \mu_{2} - 1) $$

Now, take the derivative with respect to $ \mu_{1} $

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu _{1}} = \frac{m_{1}}{\mu _{1}} + \lambda $$

Then, in general,
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu _{k}} = \frac{m_{k}}{\mu _{k}} + \lambda $$

Equate it to zero to get $ \mu _{k} = -m_{k} / \lambda $

Now substitute it in the constraint 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{K}\mu_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{-m_{k}}{\lambda} = 1 $$

Then $ \lambda = \sum_{k=1}^{K}-m_{k} = -N $

Finally, you get your answer
$$ \mu_{k} = \frac{m_{k}}{N} $$

Comment: Got it! I was ignoring the fact that $\mu$ = $[\mu_{1}, \mu_{2}, \ldots, \mu_{K} ]^T$ is a vector.